# Why are Facebook warning visitors about my links?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I post links on my site's FB page (1 or 2 per day). All links points back to my web site.

Often, especially on mobile and tablets, this warning pops up when people are clicking those links on my page:

> ## Something Went Wrong
>
> Sorry, there was a problem with this link: http://www.delbart.no/sam-den-bekymrede-katten/.
>
> You can now continue to this website, or go back to the page you were on before. Remember, only follow links from sources you trust.

The link above is just one of many ...

I've tested many of the links in debugger without finding any issues.

1. Do you know why Facebook are showing those warning messages?
2. What can I do to avoid them?

All the best :)