# Facebook trips security warning for my site, sees url as invalid, but debugger response is fine

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api

I'm totally stuck and Facebook support doesn't respond.

I'm promoting an app from a Facebook page. The link to my web page on set up worked fine.

Couple weeks ago I noticed a security warning users were getting when they clicked a link to my site from Facebook.

[image: Security warning screenshot]

The Google tells me this warning is usually issued by site suspected of redirecting or calling external javascript that looks suspicious.

I ran the URL through the URL Debugger.

There is a 301 redirect there but it's not flagged as an issue that needs fixing, only one that impacts the inability to find or download my og:image file but that's not flagged as a must fix either and the URL Debugger actually displays the image -- so it does find it.

[image: URL Debugger Screen 1]
[image: URL Debugger Screen 2]

I've localized all external Javascript calls, I've inspected the .htaccess for 301 redirects and removed all ReWrite engine instructions.

I thought maybe Facebook was tripping over my URL parameters -- my Facebook page linked to http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching/?fbp -- so I tried to change it in the setup of my page. I can't. Any formulation of the URL is called invalid:

[image]

So I have a Facebook URL debugger that basically gives the site a near-clean bill of health.
A warning to users that they shouldn't click unless it's a trusted site.
And a content mangagment system that says the URL is completely invalid.

In short, WTF?

I can't see what Facebook is tripping over. Can anyone else?

Comment: the updated_time looks very odd, and how are you doing the redirect? Is there a .htaccess affecting this?

Comment: Nope. The rewriteEngine was on in the .htaccess at root but I removed that, and there's no httpd.conf

Comment: I don't get this error from the FB debugger - it looks fine from http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching/?fbp http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching/ and http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching rather than giving an og:image tag error. Are users still getting the error?

Comment: Hmm. The 301 is gone and now it finds the og:image fine. So that's progress... Could it be that  my .htaccess file was cached and it took a couple days to flush? At any rate, doesn't solve the core problem: Still getting a security warning for those who follow link from my Facebook page, and still viewed as an "invalid url" when I try to change the link.

Comment: which of the 3 similar links causes the error and can you add a screenshot of it - right now I can't reproduce the issue from outside FB

Comment: If you visit [this Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ichingapp?ref=bookmarks) and follow any of the links to my site, you'll get the error I screenshotted above: "Something went wrong..."

Comment: https://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching and URL shorteners will work, looks like this is hitting a lot of other people - there doesn't seem to be a general solution to fit everyone. Some solutions are given here http://www.creeksidecs.com/2014/fix-sorry-problem-link-facebook-mobile/ and others on http://facebook.com/help

Comment: related quesion (no answer yet) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339299/why-are-facebook-warning-visitors-about-my-links

Comment: UPDATE: Facebook support was in touch this morning to say it had been fixed. Only it hadn't. They called back several hours later to say it had been fixed. Only it hadn't. Guy I'm dealing with is great -- informative and open, but he's not the tech team that's dealing with it, who keep calling it resolved but to no avail. Can't shed a ray of light on what might be tripping the warning, so nothing I can do to fix. More as it happens.

Comment: It's been fixed. But no word on why it went wonky in the first place. I went through Advertisers Support to get help.